# Can you reserve a Windows 10 copy inside Windows 10?

Tags: windows, upgrade, windows-10-preview, windows-10-upgrade

I'm using a Windows 10 Preview Build, and the tray icon to reserve a final copy is exclusive to Windows 7/8. The serial key for the Preview Build expires when the retail version is released.

Is there a way to reserve a copy inside Windows 10?

Comment: Did you upgrade an existing installation or do a clean install of Windows 10 Insider Preview?

Comment: It is a clean install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't reserve it as such, but as a Windows Insider, you'll get the release version when it rolls out and you'll be able to keep it as long as you stay part of the insider program (i.e. you'll get updates and the like sooner than you normally would. You'll be testing new functionality before it rolls out to the masses.)

My understanding is that Insiders and those on down-level installs that have reserved Windows 10 will be the first wave of people to have the upgrade available.

You can opt out of the Insider Program after release, but in order for your install to stay activated you will need to have come from a Windows 7/8 install with a valid license.

There has been a lot of back and forth on the topic online, [this](http://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-windows-insider-program-is-not-a-free-upgrade-path-for-xp-users-to-windows-10) is a pretty good write up.

Comment: Thanks a lot, [here's an article](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/how-turn-your-windows-10-insider-preview-windows-10-rtm) including steps on how to turn Windows 10 Preview into RTM.